# QML: Expand ColumnLayout upwards within ScrollView?

Tags: qt, qml

I am making an app that features texting. I want the text messages to be added to the column layout from the bottom to the top like a regular texting app. Where if there are only a few messages or a single message, they appear at the bottom of the view rather than the top. Right now, messages get added from top to bottom and I cannot figure out how to get it to appear the way I want. Here is currently how it looks with my code:

[image]

and here is my code:

```
Rectangle {
            id: conversationView
            SplitView.fillWidth: false
            SplitView.minimumWidth: 400
            color: "#ffffff"
            anchors.left: sideBar.right
            anchors.right: parent.right
            anchors.top: parent.top
            anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
            anchors.leftMargin: 0
            anchors.rightMargin: 0
            anchors.topMargin: 0
            anchors.bottomMargin: 0

            Rectangle {
                id: conversationTopBar
                y: 0
                height: 45
                color: "#cbcbcb"
                anchors.left: parent.left
                anchors.right: parent.right
                anchors.leftMargin: 0
                anchors.rightMargin: 0

                Label {
                    id: contactLabel
                    y: 14
                    width: 250
                    color: "#000000"
                    text: qsTr("Contact Name")
                    anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
                    anchors.left: parent.left
                    font.pointSize: 13
                    anchors.leftMargin: 20
                    font.bold: true
                }

                IconBtn {
                    x: 452
                    y: 3
                    height: contactLabel.height * 1.25
                    width: height
                    anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
                    anchors.right: parent.right
                    iconBig: 20
                    doAnimation: false
                    iconColor: "#000000"
                    btnIconSource: "../images/icons/three_dots_vertical.svg"
                    anchors.rightMargin: 10

                }
            }

            DropShadow {
                anchors.fill: conversationTopBar
                radius: 10.0
                samples: 17
                color: "#aa000000"
                source: conversationTopBar
                z: 3
            }

            SplitView {
                id: conversationSplitView
                anchors.left: parent.left
                anchors.right: parent.right
                anchors.top: conversationTopBar.bottom
                anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
                anchors.leftMargin: 5
                orientation: Qt.Vertical
                anchors.topMargin: 0

                handle: Rectangle {
                    implicitHeight: 8
                    color: "#050633"

                    Image {
                        id: horizontalDots
                        anchors.centerIn: parent.Center
                        anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
                        anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
                        source: "../images/icons/three_dots_horizontal.svg"
                        fillMode: Image.PreserveAspectFit
                        anchors.top: parent.top
                        anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
                    }

                    ColorOverlay {
                        anchors.fill: horizontalDots
                        source: horizontalDots
                        color: "white"
                        antialiasing: true
                    }
                }

                Rectangle {
                    id: messagesView
                    color: "#ffffff"
                    SplitView.fillHeight: true
                    anchors.left: parent.left
                    anchors.right: parent.right
                    anchors.top: parent.top
                    anchors.topMargin: 0
                    anchors.leftMargin: 0
                    anchors.rightMargin: 0

                    ScrollView {
                        id: messagesScroll
                        anchors.left: parent.left
                        anchors.right: parent.right
                        anchors.top: parent.top
                        anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
                        contentWidth: width
                        anchors.topMargin: 0
                        anchors.bottomMargin: 0
                        anchors.leftMargin: 0
                        anchors.rightMargin: 0

                        ColumnLayout {
                            id: columnLayout
                            height: 100
                            anchors.left: parent.left
                            anchors.right: parent.right
                            anchors.top: parent.top
                            anchors.rightMargin: 20
                            anchors.leftMargin: 20
                            anchors.topMargin: 20
                            spacing: 20

                            TextMessage {
                                messageText: "Hello World!"
                            }

                            TextMessage {
                                text: "And all who inhabit it!"
                                Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignRight | Qt.AlignVCenter
                                messageText: "Hello World!"
                            }
                        }


                    }
                }

                Rectangle {
                    id: compositionView
                    SplitView.minimumHeight: 55
                    SplitView.preferredHeight: 55
                    height: 200
                    color: "#ffffff"
                    anchors.left: parent.left
                    anchors.right: parent.right
                    anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
                    anchors.bottomMargin: 0
                    anchors.leftMargin: 0
                    anchors.rightMargin: 0

                    MessageComposer {
                        anchors.left: parent.left
                        anchors.right: sendMsgBtn.left
                        anchors.top: parent.top
                        anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
                        clearTxtBtnColor: "#0e1052"
                        textColor: "#000000"
                        anchors.rightMargin: 10
                        anchors.leftMargin: 10
                        anchors.bottomMargin: 10
                        anchors.topMargin: 10

                    }

                    IconBtn {
                        id: sendMsgBtn
                        x: 447
                        y: 8
                        anchors.right: parent.right
                        iconColor: "#0e1052"
                        anchors.rightMargin: 10
                        btnIconSource: "../images/icons/send.svg"

                    }
                }

            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would typically use a view for something like this. The relevant property in ListView is [verticalLayoutDirection](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-listview.html#verticalLayoutDirection-prop):

```
verticalLayoutDirection: ListView.BottomToTop
```

There is a chat example in Qt that does this:

https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquickcontrols-chattutorial-example.html

You can [add a ScrollBar](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls2-scrollbar.html#details) to any ListView, or [wrap the ListView in a ScrollView](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls2-scrollview.html#details).